# aspect using log4j2 performance issue

Tags: java

I am developing spring apps and I am using log4j2 to log my apps.
I am consider to using apsect and to write tol log in each function(aspect around),so now i will have a lots of log in each function in my app.is there any impact on the performance of myy app after the  Change to aspect so now i will have a lot of io log?

```
@Aspect
public class MethodLogger {
  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Loggable)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object result = point.proceed();
    Logger.info(
      "#%s(%s): %s in %[msec]s",
      MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod().getName(),
      point.getArgs(),
      result,
      System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    );
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be much impact if you use [Async Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html). However, should probably measure this yourself with [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) or by eyeballing it in a profiler. However, [profilers lie](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/profilers-hotspots-bottlenecks) at that level of precision, so take the results with a grain of salt.

Generally, log4j 2 parameterized message style `log("value1={}, val2={}", val1, val2)` is faster than the StringFormat style, and logging simple strings is fastest.

By the way, shouldn't you use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()`? If that code takes more than a millisecond there is a problem. If you follow the above advice, logging will take about 500 nanoseconds or less.

Comment: so its ok to use this aspect method and to log all of my app function before and after?

Comment: You want to do this for _every_ method in your app? That will probably have performance impact because at such a high sustained logging rate the buffer will fill up and your app will end up running as fast as you can log... But try and see...

Comment: So, how did it go? Was my answer useful?